# How to install python in android rooted device?

Tags: applications, python

I am trying to **install python in my android device** but it fails. For references i have used scripting language for android and python for android apks from the below link:

> https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a
>
> https://awesomedetect.com/how-to-install-python-on-android-without-root-and-no-internet/

I have installed these apks but still through adb shell when i try to access or run the python interpreter its showing me the following errors.

```
   ASUS_Z010D:/data/user/0/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin#
   ./python

   CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./python": library "libpython2.7.so" not found

   Aborted

  ASUS_Z010D:/data/user/0/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin#
```

Kindly help me out with this issue..!

**I need to install python and run the .py script in my android device.**

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Installing new binaries to the system itself, especially ones which require a lot of shared libraries, like Python, is going to be a nightmare. Why don't you install Termux, a compact Linux environment, and issue `apt install python` for the latest Python version, or `apt install python2` for Python2, instead?

Comment: Have you tried [PyDroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en)  IDE ?

Comment: Do you always install APKs from Google Drive links on dodgy websites? That's a good way to get malware.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/blob/wiki/RunPythonAsScript.md?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your script is trying to do you may find [QPython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3) sufficient for your needs.

It is available free from the play store and provides a python 3 environment but with some limitations on the libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

You can install python in [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en) even without root. Run: `pkg install python` or python2.